# xml parsing facing issue. Unable to replace a string

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml as follows :-

```
<Comments>
    <Comment Text="ABC">
        <Note Timestamp="3/25/2013 8:26AM" Text="Movie">
    </Note>
</Comments>
```

I want to end the Comment tag on the same line like,

```
<Comment Text="ABC"/>
```

I have applied the string replace all operation as :-

```
str.replaceAll("><Note", "/><Note");
```

But it is not working because of indefinite spaces between the comment and Notes tag.
Please note that spaces will vary each time.
Please suggest how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution with your way,

`in = in.replaceAll(">[\\s]*<Note", "/><Note");`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using Linq by replacing each `Note`-node with a new one. Simplified example handling only the first node (tested in [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/)):

```
 XElement oldStructure = 
     XElement.Parse(@"<Comment Text=""ABC"">
                       <Note Timestamp=""3/25/2013 8:26AM!"" Text=""Movie"">
                       </Note></Comment>");

 oldStructure.Dump("Original"); 

 // Replace this with some kind of lookup for each Note-element:
 var noteNode = (XElement) oldStructure.FirstNode; 

 // Create a new node. Note that it has no content:
 // (The null could be left out - left it here just to be explicit)
 var simplifiedNote = new XElement(noteNode.Name, null);
 noteNode.Attributes().ToList().ForEach(
    attrib => simplifiedNote.Add(new XAttribute(attrib.Name, attrib.Value)));

 // Replace with newly generated node - Linq will automatically use 
 // the compact format for you here, since the node has no content. 
 oldStructure.FirstNode.ReplaceWith(simplifiedNote);

 oldStructure.Dump("Final");
```

Running this in Linqpad will first dump the following:

Original:

```
<Comment Text="ABC">
   <Note Timestamp="3/25/2013 8:26AM!" Text="Movie"></Note>
</Comment>
```

Final:

```
<Comment Text="ABC">
   <Note Timestamp="3/25/2013 8:26AM!" Text="Movie" />
</Comment>
```